# Backing up my xcode projects

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, version-control, xcode

What is the best way of ensuring my xcode projects are backed up.  I am new to Mac and I see there is a timemachine programme, but isn't that for all files?

I just want to make sure my xcode files are backed up on a network drive because this is for work not pleasure.

The rest of team uses TFS and CVS etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered SVN? Or Mercurial? Xcode supports both natively and they're easy to set up. Not to mention they're free at some places (limited of course). Google beanstalk svn for a SVN repository and check this out: http://developer.apple.com/mac/articles/server/subversionwithxcode3.html

Scroll down until you see Using Subversion from Xcode.

Comment: I have not seen native Mercurial support in Xcode, and I can't find a reference in Apple's docs. How would you go about enabling it?

Answer (score 0):

Either always copy them to a separate hard drive or a flash drive when you're done. If you don't need to guarantee security, then use a service like dropbox to keep backups - They save every revision of your files, and it's free. There are other paid services if you need more storage.

If you have a second computer, you can also set up your own code repository and use that directly from Xcode.

Time Machine is also a good option, as while it's designed to back up all files, your code files should be included.

Backup is a **huge** topic, raging from simply keeping a second copy on a separate drive to multiple offsite backups of a RAID-1 array - it's all about how much the data is really worth to you if it were to be lost.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, working from home, I'd use SVN for developing, but would backup SVN to Time Machine along with [Crashplan](http://www.crashplan.com).  If you work in an office with a team of developers, use whatever they're using.  If you don't know how, learn.

Comment: The rest of the team are .NET developers using TFS